# An unhandled exception occurred: NGCC failed 08-20-2020

Tags: angular

just i have updated my angular/cli and other dependencies but while running ng serve command its giving me **An unhandled exception occurred: NGCC failed** error. Here is my angular details:

````
Angular CLI: 10.0.6
Node: 14.8.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 10.0.11
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: <error>

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.1000.6
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.1000.6
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.1000.6
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.1000.6
@angular-devkit/core              10.0.6
@angular-devkit/schematics        10.0.6
@angular/cdk                      10.1.3
@angular/cli                      10.0.6
@angular/material                 10.1.3
@ngtools/webpack                  10.0.6
@schematics/angular               10.0.6
@schematics/update                0.1000.6
rxjs                              6.6.2
typescript                        3.9.7
webpack                           4.43.0





```
````

**Error Log File : angular-errors.log**

[error] Error: NGCC failed.
at NgccProcessor.process (D:\PHENIX_WEBAPP\PHENIXBUILDPRO\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\ngcc_processor.js:69:19)
at D:\PHENIX_WEBAPP\PHENIXBUILDPRO\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:579:31
at SyncHook.eval [as call] (eval at create (D:\PHENIX_WEBAPP\PHENIXBUILDPRO\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), :9:1)
at SyncHook.lazyCompileHook (D:\PHENIX_WEBAPP\PHENIXBUILDPRO\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
at Object.webpack [as webpackFactory] (D:\PHENIX_WEBAPP\PHENIXBUILDPRO\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:55:30)
at createWebpack (D:\PHENIX_WEBAPP\PHENIXBUILDPRO\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\webpack-dev-server\index.js:21:36)
at Object.runWebpackDevServer (D:\PHENIX_WEBAPP\PHENIXBUILDPRO\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\webpack-dev-server\index.js:47:12)
at SwitchMapSubscriber.project (D:\PHENIX_WEBAPP\PHENIXBUILDPRO\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server\index.js:164:32)
at SwitchMapSubscriber._next (D:\PHENIX_WEBAPP\PHENIXBUILDPRO\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\switchMap.js:49:27)
at SwitchMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (D:\PHENIX_WEBAPP\PHENIXBUILDPRO\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:66:18)
at D:\PHENIX_WEBAPP\PHENIXBUILDPRO\node_modules@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeToPromise.js:7:24
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)

```
    
    
    
    
    can anyone help me out to solve this problem?
```

Comment: following; i've got the exact same issue. tried a lot of different things.

Answer (score 0):

ng ci to remove node modules and then install it npm install
hope this works